# Amazon S3 standalone stub server

Tags: unit-testing, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, stub

I seem to recall reading about an Amazon S3-compatible test server that you could run on your own server for unit tests or whatever. However, I've just exhausted my patience looking for this with both Google and AWS. Does such a thing exist? If not, I think I'll write one.

Note: I'm asking about Amazon S3 (the storage system) rather than Amazon EC2 (cloud computing).

Comment: somewhat related (though more geared towards production use than unit testing): http://serverfault.com/questions/283914/s3-compatible-object-storage-systems

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you thinking of [Park Place](http://github.com/technoweenie/parkplace)?

FYI, its [old home page](http://code.whytheluckystiff.net/parkplace/) is offline now.

Answer (score 4):

I think moto (https://github.com/spulec/moto) is the perfect tool for your unittests. Moto mocks all accesses to S3, SQS, etc. and can be used in any programming language using their web server.

It is trivial to setup, lightweight and fast.

From moto's README:

Imagine you have the following code that you want to test:

```
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key

class MyModel(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def save(self):
        conn = boto.connect_s3()
        bucket = conn.get_bucket('mybucket')
        k = Key(bucket)
        k.key = self.name
        k.set_contents_from_string(self.value)
```

Take a minute to think how you would have tested that in the past. Now see how you could test it with Moto:

```
import boto
from moto import mock_s3
from mymodule import MyModel

@mock_s3
def test_my_model_save():
    model_instance = MyModel('steve', 'is awesome')
    model_instance.save()

    conn = boto.connect_s3()
    assert conn.get_bucket('mybucket').get_key('steve') == 'is awesome'
```

Answer (score 2):

Park Place has moved to github:
http://github.com/technoweenie/parkplace

Answer (score 1):

[Eucalyptus](http://eucalyptus.cs.ucsb.edu/) http://eucalyptus.cs.ucsb.edu/

> EUCALYPTUS - Elastic Utility Computing
>   Architecture for Linking Your Programs
>   To Useful Systems - is an open-source
>   software infrastructure for
>   implementing "cloud computing" on
>   clusters. The current interface to
>   EUCALYPTUS is compatible with Amazon's
>   EC2 interface, but the infrastructure
>   is designed to support multiple
>   client-side interfaces.

Note that, according to the documentation, Eucalypus includes a reimplementation not only of the EC2 interface but also the S3 storage system. That storage component is called Walrus. (http://open.eucalyptus.com/wiki/EucalyptusUserGuide_v1.5.2)

Comment: I was wondering about S3 (the storage system) rather than EC2 (cloud computing).

Answer (score 1):

[Fake S3](https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3) appears to be an up-to-date reimplementation of S3, specifically designed for use in testing.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the problem of testing our S3 based code locally and actually implemented a small Java server, which emulates the S3 object API. As it might be useful to others, we setup a github repo along with a small website: http://s3ninja.net - all OpenSource under the MIT license.

It's quite small and simple and can be setup in minutes. (Being a [SIRIUS](http://sirius-lib.net) based application, statup on a moderate server takes less than a second).

Answer (score -3):

Amazon uses Xen, so you can probably just run your AMI in your own Xen installation. I'd just fire up an instance and run the tests there, though. It doesn't cost much and you should usually be fine with developing locally and infrequently testing it on their system.

Comment: I think you're talking about EC2 (cloud computing) while I'm wondering about S3 (the storage system).